# Unified Write Filter servicing on Windows 10 enterprise not working as expected

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1511, uwf

Working with Windows 10 Enterprise, fresh image, only extra software is Notepad++, all updates applied.

Now that's out of the way, we are testing Unified Write Filter (UWF), and it almost performs as expected, except for servicing mode.

The TechNet documentation states that after running the 'uwfmgr servicing enable' command and restarting that the uwf servicing account is supposed to auto login and display a screensaver. It does not do this. It reaches the standard login screen, displays UWF-Servicing as the account that is supposed to login, but it stops there.

It does execute everything in the UWF servicing script, but we require it to login and show the servicing screen saver.

And before it's posted as a reply, we have scoured the UWF documentation and have found nothing.

Comment: I have the same problem with the anniversary edition (1607), autologin stays at the login screen and no screensaver is shown. Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: Back in the Fall I finally got a tier 2 tech at MS. They do not have any current plans to fix that. They do know that it's a bug. but they do not plan on fixing it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have to implement servicing mechinism probably by disabling/enabling the filter since servicing mode is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is kind of old but the issue is still existing.

I have searched a lot and found several questions at the sites of microsoft support. All were already locked, so I will post my solution here:

**UWF-Servicing-Account does not log in automatically**

A comparison between the installed "UwfServicingMasterScript.cmd" and this example on the docs from Microsoft showed me, those are differences: https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwf-master-servicing-script

As soon as I removed the following statements, the UWF-Servicing-Account were able to login and executes all the updates. But still no Screensaver.

```
REM
REM Trigger idle maintenance tasks, and wait for completion.
REM Note that ProcessIdleTasksW will do nothing if automatic
REM maintenance is disabled.
REM

echo UpdateAgent executing maintenance tasks.
start /wait rundll32.exe advapi32.dll,ProcessIdleTasksW
echo UpdateAgent maintenance tasks completed.
```

Note: I am not entirely sure, if this is a good thing to get rid of it. As far as I understand it executes tasks which can only be executed when the system is idle.

**UWF-Screensaver does not show up**

Sometimes, or most of the time, the screensaver did not show up. There was simply the login screen with the UWF-Servicing Account preselectet. No indication that there are updates in progress.

Turns out, you can customize the screensaver: https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwf-servicing-screen-saver

After applying this registry entry (note that I changed to "Windows NT", since I am using Windows Education), the customized screensaver is showing.

**Conclusion**

Applying those fixes made the entire UWF Servicing mode finally working for me. But it really bugs me, that Microsoft is not able to fix this (as it seems) simple issue.

I hope you guys can fix your servicing mode with these changes.